# Samsung SmartThings motion sensor

Tags: smart-home, samsung-smartthings, zigbee

Does anyone know the correct cluster and end point IDs for a Samsung SmartThings motion sensor? And also the correct payloads for data extraction (like movement, temperature, battery)?

Comment: To confirm, you mean the [official SmartThings motion sensor](http://www.samsung.com/uk/smartthings/sensors-plug-f-irm-uk-v2/) and not a third party one?

Comment: Yes official samsung motion sensor.